# Passing form parameters in grails paginate and webflow

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a list of items with a checkbox beside them. These items are paginated (10 items in each page) The checkbox beside each items can be checked or unchecked. When the user clicked page 2 and then he decided to go back to page 1, the checked value should be preserved. I am trying to pass the form parameters in paginate params tag but I don't get any value.

> Item 1   [X]
> Item 2   [ ]
> ...
> Item 10
>
> page[1][2][3]

Code

`<input name='item' type='checkbox' value="a">`
`<input name='item' type='checkbox' value="a">`
`<input name='item' type='checkbox' value="a">`
`<input name='item' type='checkbox' value="a">`

```
<g:paginate max="10" offset="${myDomainOffset}" total="${totalItems}" params="${[_eventId_paginate:true,formParams:params]}"  />
```

I pass the _eventId_paginate:true because this is in a webflow.
In my 'next' event I get all the item checkbox values by doing this params.list('item')

Answer (score 0):

Using remote pagination should work. It provide data navigation without page refresh, preserving the your checkbox & other contents.


At mypage.gsp

```
<g:checkBox ../>
<div id="sortedList">
  <g:render template="mytemplate"/>
</div>
```

At _mytemplate.gsp,

```
<table>
...
</table>
<util:remotePaginate action=".." total="${..}" update="sortedList"/>
```

[More details on remote pagination](https://github.com/amitjain1982/remote-pagination)

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely take a look at this one.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution (maybe not the best one)is load all your data in one request and work with css to show and hide the group of checkbox.

The main ideia is here http://pastebin.com/KH6qewQC

Of course you have to create some functions to make your life easier, it's only the idea.